# Unable to delete AWS Batch Compute Environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-batch

I'm running into the following vague error messages while attempting to delete an AWS Batch Compute Environment.

In the output from `terraform destroy`:

> Error: error waiting for Batch Compute Environment (xyzabc) delete: timeout while waiting for resource to be gone (last state: 'DELETING', timeout: 20m0s)

Under the AWS console's "Status reason":

> INTERNAL_ERROR - Failed compute environment workflow

The resource's status goes from "DELETING" to "INVALID" after some amount of time.

How can I force the deletion of this resource?

Comment: Can you add the code you have to the question?

Comment: I'm having the same problem... did you solve this?
I tried all of these but none worked:
`terraform destroy -target aws_batch_compute_environment.this`,
`aws batch delete-compute-environment --compute-environment <COMPUTE_ENV_NAME_> --region <THE-REGION> --profile <ADMIN-ROLE>`,
`aws cloudcontrol delete-resource --type-name AWS::Batch::ComputeEnvironment --<COMPUTE_ENV_NAME_> --region <THE-REGION> --profile <ADMIN-ROLE>`